# React Data Table Component and Moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-data-table-component

I am using React Data Table Component for displaying table data - which works great!

I have a row field for lastLogin time, which is stored in MongoDB as a model like so:

```
lastLogin: [{
 type: Date,
 required: false,
}],
```

My data table component looks like so:

```
    <DataTable
      noHeader
      pagination
      paginationPerPage={15}
      paginationRowsPerPageOptions={paginationRowsPerPageOptions}
      responsive
      columns={columns}
      sortIcon={<ChevronDown />}
      className="react-dataTable"
      data={store.data}
    />
```

Using columns when I try and render the date without moment, it works fine:

```
  {
    name: 'Last Login',
    selector: (row) => row.lastLogin,
  },
```

will result in:

- row 1: 2021-11-17T01:16:55.093Z
- row 2: (empty)

However, when formatting with moment, it seems to be obtaining the previous records results.

```
  {
    name: 'Last Login',
    selector: (row) => row.lastLogin,
    format: (row) => moment(row.lastLogin).format('lll'),
  },
```

will result in:

- row 1: Jan 1, 2021 12:00 AM
- row 2: Nov 17, 2021 1:15 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... this one has been resolved... silly syntax error.

The login date on the model was setup as an array:

```
lastLogin: [{
 type: Date,
 required: false,
}],
```

Should be:

```
lastLogin: {
 type: Date,
 required: false,
},
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing details.

Answer (score 1):

This code is work correct, and the result its expected base on how the moment work.

moment work with current time as a default time to do a process, so that, if you pass a date value, then you will work and format this value, else will work and format current date.

for example:

```
var now = moment(undefined).format('lll');
console.log(now)
```

this will be equl for:

```
var now2 = moment().format('lll');
console.log(now2)
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2jzu0Lpk/)

Comment: This is not addressing the issue. The issue isn't handling undefined or empty dates - its outputting the date from the previous record.

Comment: for test, can you add key for list

Comment: OK. Original date (unformatted)
row 1: 2021-11-17T01:16:55.093Z. (ID=6169216762dd6db9d47a2b0a)
row 2: (empty)  (ID=619491bd100260d61a21f38c)

Original date (formatted with moment)
row 1: Jan 1, 2021 12:00 AM. (ID=6169216762dd6db9d47a2b0a)
row 2: Nov 18, 2021 9:59 AM (ID=619491bd100260d61a21f38c)

row 2 is getting the date from row 1 when using moment

Comment: mmmm, can you share sample of running code in sandbox to I can check it with you, since base on comment id and rows is work file, id is fine...I think the issue will be in state it self or moment not updated and follow the state when update, may if we add a key for each row in table the result changed, or by make moment updated or via prevent or re-trigger update on row